# Disable Yii-Booster(Bootstrap) radioButtonListRow Component

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

Does Anyone know how to disable [Yii booster](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/components.html) `radioButtonListRow`?

```
echo $form->radioButtonListRow($model, 'radioButtons', array(
        'Option one',
        'Option two',
    ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the htmlOptions **disabled = true**.

[radioButtonList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#radioButtonList-detail)

```
echo $form->radioButtonListRow($model, 'radioButtons', 
    array(
        'Option one',
        'Option two',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array('disabled'=>true) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try By Using as Like Following ..

```
<?php
   echo $form->radioButtonListRow($model, 'radioButtons', array(
        'Option one',
        'Option two',
    ), array('disabled' => true));
?>
```

Hopefully it will be helpful for you .... If you face any problem , Then you can inform me ..